# Is it possible to use trigger a function upon a API response in Python?

Tags: python, api, response

I'm looking to call a function upon receiving a valid response from an API call. How would I go about doing this? The logic I want to use is basically

```
function(x):
    api_instance.download_report(x)

if valid in response:
    function(x)
```

I'm just unsure how to set this up properly. I am already getting a valid response but I want to know how to use it to

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback:

```
def domyapithing(x, functobecalled):
    response= api_instance.download_report(x)
    if status(response) == 'ok':
        functobecalled(response)

def functobecalled(response):
    print(response)
```

This is an approx answer that assumes you have a function called status that returns ok if all is well.